# Visual Studio Code Slack Error Message [Slack Error Message]

Tags: visual-studio-code, slack

I turned on visual studio code today and I regularly get bugs like this, it's a strange situation because I have never installed slack. Anyone have an idea what to do with it so that it does not appear?

[image]

Comment: Maybe an extension? Otherwise I would try re-downloading if it continues to be an issue.

Comment: I have not downloaded, downloaded, uninstalled and in any case the same

Comment: Does it continue to pop up even after selecting "continue anyway"?

Comment: Yes, it displays every time no matter what button is pressed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you use codetime extension? it uses slack. if yes you should just skip "connect to slack" step.

Comment: Yes, I use it. Thank you